# Ethers filter event by uint256

Tags: ethers.js

I'm using ether's [`Provider.on`](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/provider/#Provider-on) API to listen to events. The first parameter to this function can be a `filter`. However, the offical documentation only shows how to filter by `address`. I now have an event defined as `List(uint256,uint256)`. How can I filter by the first parameter `uint256`? Specifically, I have the code below:

```js
const filter = {
  address: CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
  topics: [ethers.utils.id("List(uint256,uint256)"), tokenId, null],
};

provider.on(filter, (log, event) => {})
```

When I pass a `Number` to `topics[1]`, the `on` function throws an error

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: invalid topic (argument="topic", value=6, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=providers/5.6.2)
```

What type should I provide for `uint256` to the filter?

Answer (score 0):

Filtering on a number to get event logs requires converting the number to a hexString with a length of 32 bytes.

[Ethers.js](https://docs.ethers.org/v4/api-utils.html#hex-strings) provide two utilities for this:

**1. Convert the number in hexString**

`const hexString = ethers.utils.hexlify(number)`

*(e.g. 1 => 0x01)*

**2. Set the hexString to be 32 bytes long** (hexString left-padded with zeros to length 32 bytes, each byte being two nibbles)

`ethers.utils.hexZeroPad(hexString, 32)`

*(e.g. 0x01 => 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001)*